# Estou a tentar fazer um rollback das minhas querys só que da-me um erro no ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, transações

O codigo funciona perfeitamente sem o rollback btw.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    //Adicionar Titular query----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Titular(nifTitular,nifEntidade,nome,emailTitular,contacto)" +
    "VALUES(@nifTitular,@nifEntidade,@nome,@emailTitular,@contacto)" + "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nifTitular", Request.Form["nif"]);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nifEntidade", Request.Form["nife"]);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", Request.Form["nome"]);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailtitular", Request.Form["email"]);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contacto", Request.Form["contacto"]);

    //iNewRowIdentity passa a ter o ultimo idTitular inserido
    int iNewRowIdentityTit = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
    tran.Commit();
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Registo feito com sucesso')", true);

}
catch (SqlException exception)

{
    tran.Rollback();
    Response.Write("<p>Error code " + exception.Number + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>");

}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Da-me este erro.

> ExecuteScalar requer que o comando tenha uma transação quando a ligação atribuída ao comando estiver numa transação local pendente. A propriedade Transaction do comando não foi inicializada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro diz que o comando (instância de `SqlCommand`) precisa de uma transação associada.

[Veja que um dos construtores recebe três parâmetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor): a string SQL, a conexão e a transação.

O que você precisa é alterar a instanciação do comando para usar a transação.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Insert (...)", con, tran);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado era isso mesmo !